# Delphi XE3: [dcc32 Fatal Error] Unit5.pas(7): F1026 File not found: 'RzEdit.dcu'

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Delphi XE3 compiler cannot found Raize dcu files although the path is defined in Tools/Options/Delphi Options/Library/Library path! 
Checking the command line, there is only one path found in the -I option. All other Library paths are missing.

Current command line -I option:

```
"c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\lib\Win32\Debug"
```

Expected command line -I option:

```
"c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\Lib";
"c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\Imports";"
"c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include";
"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\Dcp";
"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\Bpl;"
"C:\Program Files\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\bin";
"c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\Lib\win32\release";
"c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\Lib\win32\debug";
"C:\Program Files\Raize\RC6\Lib\RS-XE3\Win32";
```

Why the other pathes are ignored?

Comment: Are these .dcu files compiled for XE3? DCU (Delphi Compiled Unit) files are version-dependent. If they are not for XE3, then you will have to recompile the .pas files you have.

Comment: DCC32 and all dcu files are for XE3

Comment: You might think you are using XE3, but look at that first path. Don't be helpless. Think.

Comment: You're right David. I just copied the expected command lines form a running XE7 system to show how it should look - I will correct it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In March 2018, Microsoft seems to have shipped an update to the Windows Insider builds that introduces a PLATFORM environment variable, and doing this breaks the Delphi 10.x (seattle and up IDE).

As a temporary workaround for win32 IDE targets users, create a user override PLATFORM environment variable and set the value to win32.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Windows environment variable named PLATFORM, likely created by your PC's manufacturer. Go into the Windows environment settings and remove that variable. Do not use the IDE environment settings to override the Windows environment variable with a different value. They are different variables for different purposes, but the Windows environment variable is interfering with the IDE environment in this situation.